# Gradle: Making JavaExec tasks incremental whilst debugging

Tags: gradle

I am working on a gradle project where I have a JavaExec task which runs as part of the build. When running the task normally it is incremental, i.e when the inputs/outputs haven't changed the task is skipped. As the project is built with gradle, when I run my application it builds the required modules before launching.

This works fine when using the standard 'Run' (I am using IntelliJ as my IDE), however if I launch it using 'Debug' (with the same run configuration), the JavaExec task **always** rebuilds, as the randomly assigned 'address' property in the jvmArgs has changed, despite no other changes to the inputs/outputs.

This turns the usual ~5s launch time (when all tasks are up-to-date) into 1min+, as it reruns the task.

Is there any way to force the address of the jvm that the child process uses, in order to retain the benefit of the incremental builds?

I have tried:

- debugOptions closure, eg:

  ```html
  debugOptions {
          enabled = true
          port = 12995
          server = true
          suspend = false
      }
  ```
- Explicitly settings the jvmArgs, eg:

  ```html
  jvmArgs '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=12995'
  ```

Comment: I found an issue about this for IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197548 However, no response there as well...